# Is there any way to store a text file without asking permission?

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to store a text file without asking permission?
And even if i uninstall the app data should not be deleted..

Comment: You should read Data backup overview to get a general information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup

Comment: If you don't mind the user selecting location then you can use [Intent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Storage). It doesn't require permission because it asks the user where to save the file (opens file explorer), you can then use Intent to retrieve the copy as well (user needs to select the right file though)

Answer (score 0):

currently this isn't possible, not on all/newest OS versions. e.g starting Android 10 we have Scoped Storage and without proper permission you can't save files, which won't be deleted with your app removal

developer may opt out from this feature on Android 10, but for 11 supporting it is mandatory

some docs in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage)